# Export a target's source code from Xcode project as a separate project

Tags: ios, xcode, projects

Can I export a target's source code as a separate project?

Lets say I have a target for the "lite" version of my app. I want to export this as a separate project so that I can distribute the code and assets without including any of the code and assets from the full version of the app.

Is this possible at all? I could probably write a script to do this manually, but I have a feeling that it should be possible from within Xcode.

Many thanks.

Comment: When I was working for OsiriX, i saw it had same thing, and at a single build it created  3 or 4 .app file. And each one was standalone application.

Comment: Hello! Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an export facility built-in (doesn't mean it doesn't exist of course!) but an alternate idea is to create a project and add your files to it as a "folder reference". That is, put the "common" files into a folder on disk (either under your main project or in a separate external directory). Then create a second XCode project, and add the folder to that project but choose the "folder reference" option when adding it. This essentially creates a "symbolic link" from your project out to that source folder, rather than copying the files into your project's directory structure.

Not quite what you're looking for, but might be a workable alternative for sharing one set of files across projects.

Comment: This would be ok, but we have a very complex application set up which would require more shared than just folders. Thanks for your help though.